# Remove options from select using javascript

Tags: jquery, dropdown, bootstrap-select

I have a dropdown that includes options populated from a database using php. I created a display button for each option to display under the dropdown. Each button calls a remove option function and passes its value. I'm trying to remove the option from the dropdown when one of the buttons is clicked. My function at the moment does nothing when a button is clicked.

```
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value='161'>Option 1</option>
<option value='162'>Option 2</option>
<option value='163'>Option 3</option>
<option value='164'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('161')">Option 1<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('162')">Option 2<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('163')">Option 3<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('164')">Option 4<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>

function removeOption(option) {
var optionValue = "'[value=" + "\"" + option + "\"" + "]'"; 
$(this).find(optionValue).remove();
$("#myselect").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

Comment: Check the value of `this`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `remove` part to,

```
$('#myselect option[value=' + option + ']').remove();
```

```js
  function removeOption(option) {
    $('#myselect option[value=' + option + ']').remove();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
  <option value='161'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='162'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='163'>Option 3</option>
  <option value='164'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('161')">Option 1<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('162')">Option 2<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('163')">Option 3<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('164')">Option 4<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
```

Now, it is finding the option in your select with the value of the provided value and it removes it.

**Live Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9j2or2q/1/)

Comment: And why should he do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're doing what you're doing, but this is how I'd do it. Remove the inline event handlers and use a data attribute to store the value to remove:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#myselect option[value="' + $(this).data("remove") + '"]').remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value='161'>Option 1</option>
<option value='162'>Option 2</option>
<option value='163'>Option 3</option>
<option value='164'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-remove='161'>Option 1<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-remove='162'>Option 2<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-remove='163'>Option 3<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-remove='164'>Option 4<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code works . you should use `$("#myselect option[value='your value'])` selector to remove your option

```js
function removeOption(option) {
var optionValue = "option[value='" + option + "']"; 
$("#myselect "+optionValue).remove();
$//("#myselect").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value='161'>Option 1</option>
<option value='162'>Option 2</option>
<option value='163'>Option 3</option>
<option value='164'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('161')">Option 1<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('162')">Option 2<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('163')">Option 3<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('164')">Option 4<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```js
function removeOption(option) {
$('select >option[value="'+option+'"]').remove();
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
<option value='161'>Option 1</option>
<option value='162'>Option 2</option>
<option value='163'>Option 3</option>
<option value='164'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('161')">Option 1<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('162')">Option 2<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('163')">Option 3<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onClick="removeOption('164')">Option 4<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
```